# how to set steps_per_epoch in varibale input length in fit_generator keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, autoencoder, seq2seq

I need to feed my input data to the model in such a way that sentences with the same length will be in the same batch(variable input length in LSTM).

My question is that, when we are using `fit_generator` we need to specify `steps_per_epoch , validation_steps`, but in my case I can not achieve that by simply `num_train_steps = len(Xtrain) // BATCH_SIZE`. Now my question is that where can I calculate that and pass it to `fit_generator`? I have `steps_per_epoch` in sentence_generator but I dont know how to pass it to `fit_generator`.

Is there any way we can return the length of each batch in `sentence_generator`?

This is the `fit_generator` (I don't know how to achieve `num_train_steps` and pass to fit_generator?)

```
lstm_ae_model.fit_generator(train_gen, val_gen, num_train_steps, num_val_steps, dir, NUM_EPOCHS=1)
```

So My custom generator is like this in case it can help:

```
def sentence_generator(X, embeddings):
    while True:
        # loop once per epoch
        index_sentence = 0
        import itertools
        items = sorted(X.values(), key=len, reverse=True)
        for length, dics in itertools.groupby(items, len):
            # dics is all the nested dictionaries with this length
            a = 0
            for x in dics:
                a = a+1
            num_train_steps = a
            sent_wids = np.zeros([a, length])
            for temp_sentence in dics:
                keys_words = list(temp_sentence.keys())
                for index_word in range(len(keys_words)):
                    sent_wids[index_sentence, index_word] = lookup_word2id(keys_words[index_word])
                index_sentence = index_sentence + 1
                Xbatch = embeddings[sent_wids]
                yield Xbatch, Xbatch
```

Comment: If you are training until a stop condition, you can actually use any number and a very high number of epochs, there won't be much difference.

Comment: @DanielMöller So you mean that this number do not need to be a real number?

Comment: It's just how many batches you draw per epoch, nothing else. If you have, let's say, 10 batches, and you draw 10 per epoch, one epoch will cycle the generator. If you draw one per epoch, 10 epochs will cycle the generator. If you don't want an exact number and will wait until the validation loss stops growing, then just use any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is first make a function that pre-computes the value of `steps_per_epoch` by iterating on the dataset and computing this value, and then pass it to `fit_generator`. Something like:

```
def compute_steps(X):
    import itertools
    items = sorted(X.values(), key=len, reverse=True)
    count = 0
    for length, dics in itertools.groupby(items, len):
        count += 1

    return count

spe = compute_steps(...)
gen = sentence_generator(...)
model.fit_generator(gen, steps_per_epoch=spe)
```

And do similarly for validation data.

Comment: I have a doubt here, let's say the first batch of data was generated with length=4, how can we make sure that the next time it will go for the next length to count that data, I feel it will start each time from the first.

Comment: @sariii your generator does that, each time it is called it will give the next batch.